# queueScheduler in rx.js 6.3 is synchronous - why this example doesn't causes SO If I use queueScheduler?

Tags: rxjs

I have interesting example, not a real-life task but anyway:

```
const signal = new Subject();
let count = 0;

const somecalculations = (count) => console.log('do some calculations with ', count);


console.log('Start');
signal.pipe(take(1500)/*, observeOn(queueScheduler)*/)
  .subscribe(() => {
  somecalculations(count);
  signal.next(count++);
  console.log('check if reached ', count)
});

signal.next(count++);
console.log('Stop');
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPXmzZ)

Subject.next works in synchronous way, so if i comment out observeOn(queueScheduler) - it causes Stack overflow (I control number of iterations with take operator, and on my computer if number is bigger then 1370 - it causes SO).

But if I put queueScheduler there - it works good. QueueScheduler is synchronous and somehow it allows current onNext handler run to finish running and then start next scheduled run.

Can someone explain it to me deeply with source code details? I tried to dig it but with partial success at the moment. It is about how observeOn works with QueueScheduler but answer is escaping me.

[observeOn src](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/observeOn.ts)  [QueueScheduler.ts](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/scheduler/QueueScheduler.ts)  [asyncScheduler](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/scheduler/AsyncScheduler.ts)

Comment: Because when the `queueScheduler` is specified, iteration is used instead of recursion and the notifications are queued on the heap. Look at `QueueAction` and at `AsyncScheduler.flush`. Replacing recursion with iteration is a useful mechanism for avoiding SO situations. Both are synchronous.

Comment: In https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/scheduler/AsyncScheduler.ts#L49 in flush method there is a check     
if (this.active) {
      actions.push(action);
      return;
    }
That's why flush is not performing queued work at once. Why this.active is true every time i call subject.next? And how it returns to flush again(and perform queued task) just after my subscriber onNext is over. (still debugging)

Comment: Seems like first subject.next call is recursive (it runs onNext again) and then somehow it returns to do-while from flush function (to execute queued tasks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to cartant for support. Seems like I understood why queue scheduler is working without SO.

1. When signal.next is called first time from [observeOn _next](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/observeOn.ts#L93) queueScheduler.schedule->AsyncScheduler.schedule->Scheduler.schedule causes  [QueueAction.schedule](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Scheduler.ts#L66)  to be called
2. [QueueAction.flush](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/scheduler/QueueAction.ts#L24) called. this.scheduler.flush - > QueueSchedulerFlush->[AsyncScheduler.flush](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/scheduler/AsyncScheduler.ts#L45)
3. First time queue is empty and no task is executed so this.active is false. bc of this [action.execute](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/scheduler/AsyncScheduler.ts#L58) is called. Everything is called in sync way.
4. action.execute causes onNext function to be run again. So onNext calls signal.next it goes through all 1-3 points but now this.active is true (because it is actually still previous signal.next run) and we just [queue action](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/scheduler/AsyncScheduler.ts#L50)
5. So second signal.next is handled and we return to action.execute of first signal.next call. It works in do-while and shift actions one by one. So it finished running first signal.next action - but now we have one more in queue from second signal.next recursive call. So we run action.execute for second signal.next
6. And situation is being repeated. First flush call manages all the other calls like: active is true, we add task to queue and then repeat to previous flush call and grab it from queue.

Comment: Created an article from this question: https://blog.cloudboost.io/so-how-does-rx-js-queuescheduler-actually-work-188c1b46526e

Comment: released a video course about rxjs as well) https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video